# How to control the angle and range of a light

Tags: cycles-render-engine, light

I am working on project where I am using an infrared light. I want to simulate my real scene on blender. I am using a Cycles Render engine. I want to choose a point light. It is possible to fix a level angle visual range (45 degrees in the real scene)? The viewing range (80meter in the real scene). Any explanation will be appreciated. I need to simulate this light:
[image]
Illuminating range: Standard 45Â°
Viewing range: 80m (outdoor)

---

I used the solution proposed in the [create an array of lamps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24391/how-to-create-an-array-of-lamps) to model the Infrared light mentioned above which has these properties:

- Led quantity: 96 leds.
- Wave length: 850nM.
- Illuminating range: Standard 45Â° level angle visual range
- Viewing range: 80m (outdoor).

The fisheye camera is installed in the ceiling in a room.

When we use the wave length node, the array of lamps does not emit a sufficient light!!
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Not sure what you mean... You want a point light that has angle limits, like a spotlight and a distance limit?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Are you asking for parameters of the light source or for camera parameters?

Comment: @maddin45, my question is about light source.

Comment: @Bithur, I edited my question

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24391/how-to-create-an-array-of-lamps/24392#24392

Comment: The following page may be useful for you when it comes time to add all the lights.  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24391/how-to-create-an-array-of-lamps Unless you are using geometry lights, then you should be fine for the array part.

Comment: @Bithur, it is possible to specify the wave length for a spot as in a real case.

Comment: there's a wavelengh node and blackbody (temperature)in converter submenu

Comment: @Bithur, What is the units of Strength in Light FallOff. it is in meter?

Comment: I really don't think so. As far as i know, maddin45 told you how to stop light at the exact distance you want but i wasn't able to find a good way to get a nice falloff. Someone with better math or coding knowledge could do better.

Comment: @startingBlender if you emit light in a wavelength that is not visible... what are you expecting to see?

Comment: @cegaton, you are great. Excuse, I suppose that the camera is sensible to infrared wavelength!!

Comment: @startingBlender I think in terms of your simulation the wavelength should not be relevant, unless you are to create some object that has a material that transforms the infrared energy into something that can be represented with the colors of the spectrum.

Comment: visible light and its wave length : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visible_spectrum

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you want to keep it in cycles, you'd better model your own lamp as anything can cast light. This way you can control the shape and with a light falloff node you can control the distance.

[image: modeled spot]

assign the correct shader : emission for the face you want to cast light, plastic or anything else for the other parts.

Comment: Thanks, it seems very cool, but I have to change the color to white as in a real case.

Comment: easy as a click on color (emission node)

Comment: You cant control the angle with this.. you would have to model the leds also..

Comment: why not a array of modeled leds :) but the angle can be controled with the depth of the emitting faces inside the spot.

Comment: because the render times would be ridiculous! Array of Spot lamps maybe..

Comment: sure, that's why a simple model fits a basic solution. But that's what makes cycles so powerful, you can make things as complex as you need.

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't use the GPU render because I have mac pro with Intel HD Graphics 4000! So render times will be very important!

Comment: keep it simple then.

Comment: To control the angle more precisely you can use the *facing* output of the *layer weight* node in conjunction with a *math* > *is less than*/*is greater than* and multiply that by the *light falloff*'s output.

Comment: @PGmath Really interesting, 'less than' makes the single face's emitted light acting like a spotlight (round and sharp) unless you use a subdivided smoothed curved surface as emitter, giving interesting effects too!

Answer (score 4):

Add a **Spot Lamp** to the scene, switch to **Blender Render** engine and set the Spotlights size(angle) and distance(falloff).

[image]

Position it in the scene like you want, the visual spotlights guides will help, you should see the spotlight cone and range.

Switch to Cycles if you want, but the falloff will not work there, you will have to adjust the light's strength. If you like you can use volumetrics to visualize the lights cone in render:

[image]

It will look like this:

[image]

Comment: there is a node on cycles for light falloff.

Comment: Sure there is, but its not that important (strength will do) nor physically correct.

Answer (score 3):

**Disclaimer:**
This answer might be better suited as a comment, but since you can not post images in comments I created an answer instead.

Sounds to me like you want to use a spot light. Spots work similar to point lights but also have an opening angle. Unfortunatly Cycles only supports round spots, not rectangular ones.

About the viewing range: In real life light will not stop abruptly, so this parameter does not really make sense in a physically based renderer like Cycles. You can however mix the emission shader of the spot with a holdout shader depending on the ray length to only make it illuminate objects in a certain range.

[image]

The result looks something like this:

[image]

At a certain range from the lamp the lightsource is treated as black. This creates the hard round 'light borders' to the left. The soft 'light border' to the right is where the opening angle of the spot ends.

Comment: Thanks, but I remark that the shadow is not very clear and in the real case, the Infrared light is a monochromatic, so we get grayscale image not RGB. So, I think I have to choose precisely the diffuse of the spot.

Comment: @startingBlender I only wanted to demonstrate a method to make the light stop at a certain distance here.

Comment: really interesting but i'm trying to make a falloff with raylength. Something like an inverted exponential. As you can guess, my maths are not good.