# How is this duplicating light along a mesh done in blender scene?

Tags: modeling, lighting

Yesterday while I was studying this BlenderSwap subway tunnel scene: *https://www.blendswap.com/blend/8421*, I encountered something every strange.

In the below screenshot I have deleted every irrelevant data and leave only the special part:

[image: Subway Tunnel]

As you can see in the screenshot, **there is a planar mesh and a single lamp - however the lamp is magically duplicated along what seemingly to be the "path" of the mesh**, if we shall call it this way.

However in the scene there is no array modifier or anything I can recognize - there does seem to be a parenting relationship between the mesh and the lamp, but exactly how is this done?

I know it's not ideal to append a file but this question is quite software/data specific, so I have appended the scene file for your reference: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lLjSAy6WDfge0fK5dLbxBaHxe3xFGaFR

Remark: The *.blend* file requires Blender 2.8

Comment: Use instancing to Verts: Explained in this answer: [How to create an array of lamps?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24391/how-to-create-an-array-of-lamps)

Comment: For the file in question the lamp is using instancing to faces, but is the same principle.