# geometry nodes and light

Tags: lighting, geometry-nodes

I am trying to model a grid of lights using geometry nodes. I combine several nodes like grid, instance on points, etc. as depicted in the following figure:
[image]

I can attach instances of any mesh to the points, but it does not work for light.

Any clue ?

Regards.

Comment: I would guess because light has no geometry it won’t work. Same problem with normal array modifier, which don’t work with lights either.

Comment: @Chris Is object node in the roadmap of everything node ? Or will it somehow add light at a point (like curve, point cloud and volume isn't geometry but still is in geometry node)

Comment: i have no idea what the roadmap is... ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to look this up, but.. from [the manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/object_info.html#inputs), it seems you have to check the 'As Instance' field of the *Object Info* node:

> **As Instance:**
> Output the entire object as single instance instead of
> realized geometry. This allows instancing non-geometry object types,
> because the output will contain an instance of the object.

It also works, if you put the light in a collection, and use the *Collection Info* node.

[image]

You can't *Realize Instances*, it seems, because the lamps are not geometry, and they disappear if you apply the GN modifier.

Comment: nice!! +1...and you are a manual reader too...i can't believe! ;)

Answer (score 4):

Enable instancing in *Object Properties*, then parent a light to the object:

[image]

[image]

Of course if you want to parent the lights to only some vertices of the object, you need to duplicate the object, delete vertices that aren't supposed to instance lights, and disable instancer rendering in the options visible in the first screenshot above.

Comment: i love working workarounds so +1, although Robin's solution is a tiny bit better ;)

Comment: @Chris of course, I simply didn't know it's possible in geo... :)

Comment: Me too…love learning new ways and solutions