Apply Geometry Nodes Modifier that has instances of lights
I recently made this very handy randomizer for a tri-lighting setup in geometry nodes:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xwjFmnY-d6M
However, when I discover a seed that I like and want to apply it, I get an error saying that there are no meshes because the lights aren't meshes.
Is there by any chance another way to get the light setup to be realized for further manual manipulation?

Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See How to upload an image to a post? or GIF

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/247271/geometry-nodes-and-light

Thanks for that resource! It's still unfortunately not working. Any possible hints as to why? https://i.sstatic.net/Hl9a53lO.png

(Using Blender 4.2.1)
An approach is to split the original GeometryNodes modifier in two GN modifiers:

The "Model" is computing and storing attributes. It is making a mesh and it can be applied to freeze a configuration.
The "View" is adding lights based on position and attributes stored by the "Model". It can not be applied because it is not making a mesh.

Follows an example (NB: two screenshots were superimposed to make this figure):

Model GN:
1. 3 vertices of an icosphere are drawn randomly ; others are deleted.
2. The Seed parameter of the RNG is controlled by the GN input panel.
3. The index to pick instances in the "Lights" collection is randomized and stored as an attribute named "light" (see dark pink nodes).
View GN:
4. An Instance on Points node is used to spawn lights picked in a collection.
5. The Instance Index parameter is recovered from the attribute "light" stored at step 3.
6. The Position to place a light and to orient it is recovered from the points generated by the "Model" GN at step 1.
A bonus is that after the "Model" GN is applied, lights position and attributes can be adjusted in Edit Mode as for any regular mesh:

Go to the menu entry Mesh>Set Attribute to modify the value of the attribute highlighted in the Object Data Properties panel for the selected point(s).
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.1+)

Side note: The Seed parameter can be stored also as an attribute if you want to keep its value at hand even after the "Model" modifier is applied.

Thank you for this technique—I will have to give it a try!
