# Can you add lights to multiple linked objects simultaneously?

Tags: modeling, lighting, linked-data, instances

I have a scene with multiple streetlamps, they are all the same mesh and linked to each other (when I edit the mesh of one of them it is applied to all the other objects as well).
I am struggling to find the fastest way to add spotlights now. since spotlights are not mesh, I can't just add them in edit mode to have them on all the lights but surely there has to be another way that I am missing to do what I want.
So far the best solution I found is to add a spotlight and set one of the streetliamps as a parent then move it in the right position and from there i can just copy paste the spotlight, change the parent to the next streetlamp and repeat that process until all the lamps have a light. Still not ideal but at least faster than having to handplace every single light.
Is there any faster way to do it? Is it possible to make use of the linked objects?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could use collection instances but you'll need to recreate all the copies. Or add a light bulb mesh and give it Emission shader but I guess you want a real light

Comment: Check out this question which goes over how to create an array of lights which might be useful if all of your street lamps are in a orderly arrangement (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24391/how-to-create-an-array-of-lamps). You can also link object data between the lights so that they all behave the same (intensity, color, etc.) but I know that doesn't help with placement.