# How to simulate an Infrared light source model

Tags: rendering, blender-internal-render-engine, camera, light

I want to simulate a real image captured by an infrared camera under an infrared light source illumination. The length  of infrared wavelength is 850nm. How does we do such experimentation on blender. Is it possible to do it?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24371/how-to-control-the-angle-and-range-of-a-light

Comment: What is the visual result you expect? Are you trying to achieve thermal imaging like effect, or one of those monochrome night-vision like images? Can you provide a few image examples of what you are trying to do? Either way that is probably best achieved in post production with some filter effects in the compositor nodes or something.

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos  I did not talking about thermal imaging. I need monochrome night-vision like images.

Comment: maybe related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48944/how-do-i-work-with-grayscale/48966#48966

Answer (score 3):

Tristimulus models such as RGB are effectively a wide band visible spectral light emulation, making such experiments impossible.

Even spectral based renderers might have a hard time with spectral rendering when dealing with non-visible infra red or ultra violet, depending on how they have been designed.